# Anyone have experience with Seam 3?

Tags: seam, seam3

Currently I'm working on a large multi-user, communication-heavy project which uses Seam 2 and RichFaces 3.

It's been in development for about 5 weeks now.

I'm at a stage where I've found some limitations with RichFaces and will need to start using Seam Remoting to re-implement certain (major) functionality

If I'm not mistaken, Seam 3 has more advanced Remoting as opposed to Seam 2. I still think I might need to make use of RichFaces but with JSF 2.0 and Seam 3 offering greater Ajax support, it may be reduced.

Seeing that Seam 3 is in beta, I was wondering if it is worth migrating over and how stable it is at the moment.

There's at least a four to five more months of development left. Where do you envision Seam 3 to be at the end of that period?

Also, how have you found the migration process to be?

Any tips and experiences will be appreciated.

Comment: please specify exactly what limitations of RichFaces or Seam 2 are hindering you and what you want to do with Seam Remoting.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753274/a4jrepeat-dynamically-appending-a-new-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use Seam 3 now, even if you think you have 4 - 5 months to go.

Its still very early beta, and things might get different, and lots of bugs might be there which will make your project extend even further.

However, what you can do is use Java EE 6 with JSF 2 and Richfaces 4 (Or Primefaces which I would prefer), and then only use the Remoting module of Seam, which should be pretty stable enough.

Then you can slowly migrate towards Seam 3 when it becomes more stable.

---

Alternatively, stick with jQuery and Seam 2 Remoting

Comment: Also, besides the Beta stage there are a lot of modules missing. I wouldn't use SEAM 3 for production just yet.